# How to access elements of sorted list in R

Tags: r

I have the result of the sort function in R as the following:
walk 
23,
facebook 
21,
news 
20, 
net 
17 
Here it is showing every words with its corresponding frequencies. Suppose "sortList" is the variable name, and I am able to access the "facebook"'s frequency(23) by sortList[[1]]. How can I access the text "facebook"?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example please

Comment: Maybe `names(sortList)[1]` - though it's unclear from your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double brackets access the data in a specific list element (see [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el))
But if you are dealing with a named list e.g.

```
sortList = list(walk=23, facebook=21, news=20, net=17)
```

It's as easy as

```
sortList["facebook"]
$facebook
[1] 21
```

or to access the names the names() function.

```
names(sortList)
[1] "walk"     "facebook" "news"     "net"
```